# Using pg_dump and psql to transfer table with timestamp into another Db

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I am using the following *pg_dump* and *psql* command lines through the terminal in order to transfer my table from one database to another.

```
pg_dump -U postgres -t public.table1 database1 | psql -U postgres -d database2
```

But the problem is that the *table1* from the *database1* is getting pasted into *database2* with the same name, i.e. *table1*. I want to add the timestamp also into the name, something like **table1_18_11_2014_20_45_30**, in order to keep a track on when the transfer operation was taken place (in this case, at 20:45:30 hours on 18th Nov 2014). Any idea how to do this? Thx.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transfer the table you can alter the table name with `ALTER TABLE table RENAME TO table_datestamp`. I am not aware of automatic renaming tables while doing backup.

Or you can modify sql dump file and then run the script after modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

Thx Mladen, I think renaming the table after dump operation is easier than altering the sql dump file itself. Following is my Python script to do the same.

```
import time
import psycopg2
import os

connection3 = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='db_archieve' user='postgres' password='pass123'")
cursor5 = connection3.cursor()
os.system('pg_dump -U postgres -t public.final_table db_final | psql -U postgres -d db_archieve')
current_time = time.strftime("%c")
current_time_tbl = '"' + current_time + '"'
cursor5.execute("alter table final_table rename to %s;" % (current_time_tbl))
connection3.commit()
```